# Problem with help.ubuntu.com search engine

Tags: search, engine

I'm looking for decision preview photo and folders and help.ubuntu.com doesn't show own site in results. What I should do for correct searching?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jpeg preview in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458536/jpeg-preview-in-nautilus)

Answer (score -1):

Try searching Google (or another search engine) for “preview files site:help.ubuntu.com” (without quotes). The site: search term allows you to only search one Web site. Perhaps the page you are looking for is https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-preview.html.en or https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-preview.html.en. The main page for that is https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files.html.en.